# I tried to drop foreign key from my table 'login_data' but it shows like Can't DROP 'login_type'; check that column/key exists

Tags: mysql

```
alter table login_data drop index login_typw;
```

> 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'login_type'; check that column/key exists

```
alter table login_data drop index login_type;
```

> 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'login_type'; check that column/key exists

```
alter table login_data drop foreign key login_data_ibfk_1;
```

> 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'login_data_ibfk_1'; check that column/key
>   exists

Comment: ok, they don't exist

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
SHOW CREATE table login_data
```

To see the foreign key in your table which will be something like

```
login_data_ibfk_1
```

Then, the below will work.

```
alter table login_data drop foreign key login_data_ibfk_1;
```